# Android's GridView and a problem with size of its elements

Tags: android, gridview

I'm trying to make each element of GridView the same size (width and height) without any luck. Is there somewhere an option to do that or do I have to really make my own GridView like View?

Comment: You have 5 open questions, 4 of which have valid answers. You should accept answers from people who have answered your questions, and upvote response that have lead you in the right direction or offered useful insight. My epeen won't grow if I answer your question and you don't mark it as answered :(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `columnWidth` in XML? That won't help you with getting them all the same height, but it would help with getting them all the columns the same width.

Comment: That only makes each element the same width, but the height still remains unchanged. I was thinking about adding a blank image beneath my elements layout so that image would spread the height evenly for each element.

Comment: Have you looked into setting the `layout_weight` for each subview to the same value? Not sure how that would affect a `GridView`

Comment: Well I don't think that would help me. Anyway I've created an image 200x200px and it seems to work. It's a dirty way but it works.